# Is Google Analytics tracking actually safe to use on pages with sensitive information?

Tags: javascript, google, user-tracking

When enabling Google Analytics, they ask you to embed a JS snippet on every page you want to track. That's fair enough.

But when you add this code are you giving Google the ability to scrape the content on every single page that the code is loaded on? Presumably by giving Google access to run a JS file that they control, that JS file could edited to steal everything in the DOM?

I'm not suggesting that Google actually do this, but is it theoretically a risk?

Comment: I don't know if it works specifically for Google Analytics, but you might want to look into setting up subresource integrity. Troy Hunt (of Have I Been Pwned fame) has [a pretty thorough article discussing this](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-javascript-supply-chain-paradox-sri-csp-and-trust-in-third-party-libraries/).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Unfortunately, GA is designed in such a way that  [SRI does not work](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/Google-Analytics-support-for-SRI-hash/td-p/585853).

Comment: yes, absolutely. every script runs with full user perms. every script can do anything a user can and more.

Comment: @Anders I thought as much in this specific case, but it's still a useful technique to have in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every third-party script has the ability to load every page on the same domain so the risk exists.

If you really need to track analytics on sensitive pages, consider doing it server side, and be sure to check that an analytics snippet loaded on another page couldn't load the sensitive page and read its contents (via AJAX, for example).

Comment: I didn't know about your first point. It makes sense, I just hadn't considered it. I was leaning towards server-side tracking, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the implicit trust you are granting Google, Google's servers, Google's developers, and other transitive parties - you are also sharing with them ALL of your URLs.

Hopefully this should not matter, however if you have any sensitive information in your URL - e.g. tokens, keys, ids, etc - these will be exposed.

(Of course if you have sensitive data in your URLs you have other problems, and are likely exposing this information elsewhere - but it does mean you are increasing your exposure.)

Comment: I'm less fussed about the URLs. They're not storing any information. Thanks though.

Comment: @MaxWoolf That's good, it really shouldnt be a problem in itself. I only mention it because it often IS a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late to the party, but I believe this needs a deeper discussion.

First of all, yes. Embedding third-party code on your site gives large amount of power over your pages to the third-party. However, this code can easily be viewed by anyone, whether you or the users in most browsers. This means, if there actually was any harmful code, these companies would risk getting exposed (though they could only target individuals, to drastically reduce the chances of getting caught). It is therefore unlikely that a larger company would do this. You are however still providing large amount of data to these companies, especially when it comes to analytics solutions.

If you are concerned though, perhaps because you handle sensitive data, you can use self-hosted open-source tracking solution, such as [Matomo](https://matomo.org/). With Matomo, all the code and data is hosted on your own server, therefore under your control.

Comment: `this code can easily be viewed by anyone` The problem here is they could be sending malicious code to targeted individuals, this is where SRI comes in handy.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald yes, there still would be a chance of being spotted though. But I agree, that may be a concern. Apparently the NSA refused to use some of its techniques on hackers, as they feared there was bigger chance they could get detected, so there is some chance. Though it would be very rare, sort of last resort.